# Возможно ли добавить графический редактор форм Qt в CLion?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

Мне страшно нравится среда CLion, но проекты для Qt мне приходится писать во встроенном в Qt редакторе форм (который упрощает работу с интерфейсом, по мне так гораздо удобнее чем ручное создание всех кнопок меток и так далее, тыкать туда сюда ручками свойства). Вопрос вот в чём, возможно ли присобачить редактор форм в CLion, как в какой нибудь MS Visual Studio?

Comment: В CLion такого нет. ИМХО, дизайнер нужен только для прототипов интерфейса, в дальнейшем этот набросок переводится в код, который будет компактнее и более расширяемый чем сгенерированный.

Comment: Ну просто условные лабораторки по криптографии я пишу на Qt, и собачить интерфейсы граф редактором в разы быстрее и проще, но среда в CLion удобнее в разы((

Comment: у CLion есть возможность добавлять в меню утилит сторонние приложения - возможно это как то Вам поможет

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить в external tools вызов `designer.exe` с нужным вам `.ui` файлом. Также можно сделать ассоциацию данного расширения с этой программой, чтобы автоматически запускать дизайнер.